# How to use a web service and return it from Java Class to JSP

Tags: java, web-services, jsp

I am trying to develop an small software that converts inputs coming from a form into a class that uses the Web Service converter for temperatures. I just can get how to call the function and which way to pass these arguments to the WS function and if my form is correctly done. Can someone verify what i have done so far?

This is my JSP form:

```
<form name="converter" class="form-group" method="get" action="WSTutorial">
              <label>Input</label><br>
              <input type="text" name="temperature"/><br><br>
              <label>From:</label><br>
              <select name="fromUnit">
                  <option value="celsius">Celsius</option>
                  <option value="fahrenheit">Fahrenheit</option>
              </select><br>
              <label>To:</label><br>
              <select name="toUnit">
                  <option value="celsius">Celsius</option>
                  <option value="fahrenheit">Fahrenheit</option>
              </select><br><br>
              <input type="submit" value="Convert" class="btn btn-info"/>
          </form>
```

This is java class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class WSTutorial {


    private int temp;
    private String fromUnit;
    private String toUnit;


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("text/html");

        temp = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("temperature"));
    fromUnit = request.getParameter("fromUnit");
    toUnit = request.getParameter("toUnit");


    }

    private static double convertTemp(java.lang.String temperature, java.lang.String fromUnit, java.lang.String toUnit) {
        net.webservicex.ConvertTemperature service = new net.webservicex.ConvertTemperature();
        net.webservicex.ConvertTemperatureHttpGet port = service.getConvertTemperatureHttpGet();
        return port.convertTemp(temperature, fromUnit, toUnit);
    }



}
```

What is the right way to call this function? Do my arguments match the required function parameters?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it will look something like this:

Form Actions calls a `servlet`

```
<form name="converter" class="form-group" method="get" action="/WSTutorial">
              <label>Input</label><br>
              <input type="text" name="temperature"/><br><br>
              <label>From:</label><br>
              <select name="fromUnit">
                  <option value="celsius">Celsius</option>
                  <option value="fahrenheit">Fahrenheit</option>
              </select><br>
              <label>To:</label><br>
              <select name="toUnit">
                  <option value="celsius">Celsius</option>
                  <option value="fahrenheit">Fahrenheit</option>
              </select><br><br>
              <input type="submit" value="Convert" class="btn btn-info"/>
          </form>
```

WSTutorial extends HttpServlet:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class WSTutorial extends HttpServlet {


    private int temp;
    private String fromUnit;
    private String toUnit;

    public void init() throws ServletException {
    // Do required initialization

    }


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        temp = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("temperature"));
        fromUnit = request.getParameter("fromUnit");
        toUnit = request.getParameter("toUnit");

         out.println("<h1> Temp is " + convertTemp(temp ,fromUnit,toUnit) + "</h1>");
out.close();
        }

    private static double convertTemp(java.lang.String temperature, java.lang.String fromUnit, java.lang.String toUnit) {
        net.webservicex.ConvertTemperature service = new net.webservicex.ConvertTemperature();
        net.webservicex.ConvertTemperatureHttpGet port = service.getConvertTemperatureHttpGet();
        return port.convertTemp(temperature, fromUnit, toUnit);
    }

}
```

And th servlet is defined in the `web.xml`

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>WSTutorial</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>WSTutorial</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>WSTutorial</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/WSTutorial</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I will try it like that. Thanks a million!!